# Srcset and downloading an image

Tags: html, responsive-design, srcset

Is it possible to use srcset to specify an image for download?

Here is my example, lets say I have 4 images:

```
small.jpg  
medium.jpg  
large.jpg  
original-huge.jpg
```

I want the browser to only load small, medium or large as displayed and never display the huge one, but when user right click the image and clicks "view image" or "save image as" to always download the original-huge one regardless of screen size.

Is this possible using srcset?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think there's anything built in for this. Generally if downloading the image is an expected action you would have a button/input of some sort rather than relying on the browsers context menu functions.

Comment: I confirm the @HubertNNN answer. The only way to archive this is using Javascript. If you are trying to code an image visualizer I suggest you to use [PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com) library that is really powerful and intuitive.